# PySpark/Hive: how to CREATE TABLE with LazySimpleSerDe to convert boolean 't' / 'f'?

Tags: python, csv, hive, pyspark, hive-serde

Hello dear stackoverflow community,

here is my problem:

---

A) I have data in csv with some boolean columns;
unfortunately, the values in these columns are `t` or `f` (single letter);
this is an artifact (from Redshift) that I cannot control.

B) I need to create a spark dataframe from this data, 
hopefully converting `t -> true` and `f -> false`.
For that, I create a Hive DB and a temp Hive table
and then `SELECT *` from it, like this:

```
sql_str = """SELECT * FROM {db}.{s}_{t} """.format(
             db=hive_db_name, s=schema, t=table)
df = sql_cxt.sql(sql_str)
```

This works, I can print df, and it gives me all my columns with correct data types. 
But:

C) If I create the table like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {db}.{schema}_{table}({cols})                    
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED                                                                                          
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|t'                                                                                     
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION ...
```

, this converts all my `t` and `f` to Nulls.

So:

D) I found out about `LazySimpleSerDe` that presumably must do what I mean (convert `t` and `f` to `true` and `false` on the fly). From `https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties` (quote):

```
"""
hive.lazysimple.extended_boolean_literal
Default Value: false
Added in: Hive 0.14 with HIVE-3635
LazySimpleSerDe uses this property to determine 
if it treats 'T', 't', 'F', 'f', '1', and '0' as extended, 
legal boolean literals, in addition to 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'. 
The default is false, which means only 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' 
are treated as legal boolean literals.
"""
```

According to this (or at least so I think), I now create a table in Hive DB like this:

```
create_table_sql = """
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {db_name}.{schema}_{table}({cols})
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = "\|")
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
    LOCATION '{loc}'
    TBLPROPERTIES ('hive.lazysimple.extended_boolean_literal'='true')
    """.format(db_name=hive_db_name,
               schema=schema,
               table=table,
               cols=",\n".join(cols),
               loc=location)

return sql_cxt.sql(create_table_sql)
```

This does create a table,
I can again see all the columns with proper data types, 
the `df.count()` is correct, but `df.head(3)` still 
gives me all values for my boolean columns == Null.

(:___

---

I tried for hours different variants for my CREATE TABLE...

- with or without SERDEPROPERTIES,
- with or without TBLPROPERTIES,
- with "FIELDS TERMINATED BY..." or without,

etc.

All give me either

- Null in place of 't' and 'f', or
- an empty df (nothing from `df.head(5)`), or
- a syntax error, or
- some 100 pages of Java exceptions.

The real problem is, I would say, that there is no single example of CREATE TABLE with `LazySimpleSerDe`
that does the job that is described in the docs.

I would really, really appreciate your help or any ideas. I pulled out almost all my hair.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [patches in jira issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3635):

```
SET hive.lazysimple.extended_boolean_literal=true;
```

So for example, if you have a tab-delimited text file, containing header rows, and 't'/'f' for true false:

```
create table mytable(myfield boolean)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\t'
lines terminated by '\n'
location '/path'
tblproperties (
    'skip.header.line.count' = '1'
);
...
select count(*) from mytable where myfield is null; <-- returns 100% null
...
SET hive.lazysimple.extended_boolean_literal=true;
select count(*) from mytable where myfield is null; <-- changes the serde to interpret the booleans with a more forgiving interpretation, yields a different count
```