# pyspark.sql SparkSession load() with schema : Non-StringType fields in schema make all values null

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, schema

Hi,
I am having trouble using non-StringType as a part of the schema that I use in loading a csv file to create a dataframe.

I was expecting the given schema to be used to convert each field of each record to corresponding data type on the fly while loading.
Instead, all I get is null values.

Here is a simplified way of how to reproduce my problem. In this example, there is a small csv file with four columns that I want to treat, correspondingly, as str, date, int, and bool:

```
python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jun 17 2018, 12:13:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyspark
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> 
>>> data_flnm = 'four_cols.csv'

>>> lines = [ln.rstrip() for  ln in open(data_flnm).readlines()[:3]]
>>> lines
['zzzc7c09:66d7:47d6:9415:87e5010fe282|2019-04-08|0|f', 'zzz304fa:6fc0:4337:91d0:05ef4657a6db|2019-07-08|1|f', 'yy251cf0:aa11:44e9:88f4:f6f9c1899cee|2019-05-13|0|t']


>>> parts = [ln.split("|") for ln in lines]
>>> parts
[['zzzc7c09:66d7:47d6:9415:87e5010fe282', '2019-04-08', '0', 'f'], ['zzz304fa:6fc0:4337:91d0:05ef4657a6db', '2019-07-08', '1', 'f'], ['yy251cf0:aa11:44e9:88f4:f6f9c1899cee', '2019-05-13', '0', 't']]

>>> cols1 = [StructField('u_id', StringType(), True), StructField('week', StringType(), True), StructField('flag_0_1', StringType(), True), StructField('flag_t_f', StringType(), True)]
>>> cols2 = [StructField('u_id', StringType(), True), StructField('week', DateType(), True), StructField('flag_0_1', IntegerType(), True), StructField('flag_t_f', BooleanType(), True)]
>>> sch1 = StructType(cols1)
>>> sch2 = StructType(cols2)
>>> sch1
StructType(List(StructField(u_id,StringType,true),StructField(week,StringType,true),StructField(flag_0_1,StringType,true),StructField(flag_t_f,StringType,true)))
>>> sch2
StructType(List(StructField(u_id,StringType,true),StructField(week,DateType,true),StructField(flag_0_1,IntegerType,true),StructField(flag_t_f,BooleanType,true)))

>>> spark_sess = SparkSession.builder.appName("xyz").getOrCreate()
19/09/10 19:32:16 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

>>> df1 = spark_sess.read.format('csv').option("nullValue", "null").load([data_flnm], sep='|', schema = sch1)
>>> df2 = spark_sess.read.format('csv').option("nullValue", "null").load([data_flnm], sep='|', schema = sch2)

>>> df1.show(5)
+--------------------+----------+--------+--------+
|                u_id|      week|flag_0_1|flag_t_f|
+--------------------+----------+--------+--------+
|zzzc7c09:66d7:47d...|2019-04-08|       0|       f|
|zzz304fa:6fc0:433...|2019-07-08|       1|       f|
|yy251cf0:aa11:44e...|2019-05-13|       0|       t|
|yy1d2f8e:d8f0:4db...|2019-07-08|       1|       f|
|zzz5ccad:2cf6:44e...|2019-05-20|       1|       f|
+--------------------+----------+--------+--------+
only showing top 5 rows

>>> df2.show(5)
+----+----+--------+--------+
|u_id|week|flag_0_1|flag_t_f|
+----+----+--------+--------+
|null|null|    null|    null|
|null|null|    null|    null|
|null|null|    null|    null|
|null|null|    null|    null|
|null|null|    null|    null|
+----+----+--------+--------+
only showing top 5 rows

>>>
```

I tried a few different versions of .read(...)....load(...) code. 
None produce the expected result.
Please advice.  Thank you!

PS: could not add tags "structfield" and "structtype" : not enough reputation (__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While parsing, youu need to read the flag_t_f column as string. The following schema will work:

```
StructType(List(StructField(u_id,StringType,true),StructField(week,DateType,true),StructField(flag_0_1,IntegerType,true),StructField(flag_t_f,StringType,true)))
```

After that you can add a boolean column to the dataframe if required:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = df.withColumn("flag_t_f", 
      f.when(f.col("flag_t_f") == 'f', 'False')
      .when(f.col("flag_t_f") == 't', 'True')          
     )
```

If you have more than one boolean columns having values as 'f' and 't' you can convert all of those by iterating over all the columns

```
cols = df.columns
for col in cols:
    df = df.withColumn(col, 
        f.when(f.col(col) == 'f', 'False')
         .when(f.col(col) == 't','True')
         .otherwise(f.col(col))
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I haven't tried your solution yet but it sounds fantastic! :) 
I was already doing something similar but much more ugly: 
created the schema where all columns were "StringType" and then changed all but those that were indeed of StringType one by one (and there are hundreds of them). 
Thanks a lot! :) but: why? and where is this documented?

Comment: Also: I tried to solve this problem in a totally different way using LazySimpleSerde but also couldn't find a solution: maybe you would like to take a look? –– 
[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811034/pyspark-hive-how-to-create-table-with-lazysimpleserde-to-convert-boolean-t [/link]

Comment: Could you please help a little more?
What would be the correct syntax if I have more than one boolean field? 
Should I repeat the code above for each column (
    df=df.withColumn(col1....
    df=df=df.withColumn(col2...

-- or I could combine all in one statement? 
My question is actually about performance: which solution would be better?
Thanks!!!

Comment: if you need specific datatype in dataframe, I would suggest to read in string nd then cast in dataframe. Reading in string is always good, specially in  case of numbers if they come up with space then it becomes difficult to understand why is it coming as null.

Comment: I have added the code to iterate over all the columns. If you know the column names that you want to covert you can replace  df.columns with the known list of columns.